# Is there any way I can make this code any simpler?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm a beginner programmer learning C through the CS50 online course provided by Harvard. This program is supposed to prompt the user for a Height and when they type the height(1-8), a pyramid is printed according to the height inputted by the user. When you type 2, it outputs a tiny pyramid 2 lines tall with 2 spaces in the middle. My program does what it's supposed to do but I'm sure there's a better way than nesting loops.

I've tried making one loop for one side of the pyramid instead of 2 loops. I think it was the right approach but it was executed horribly.

```
{

    for (int spaces = height - line; spaces > 1; spaces--)
    {
        printf(" ");

    }
    for (int hashes = 0; hashes < line + 1; hashes++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("  ");

    for (int hashes = 0; hashes < line + 1; hashes++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
    for (int spaces = height - line; spaces > 1; spaces--)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

Comment: [codereview.se] is a better place to ask for advice on improving coding style for working code.

Comment: There isn't really much simplification you can make, although since you have the same loops multiple times, you could put those into functions.

Comment: Instead of using `printf`, you should use `putchar` for a single character.

Comment: You did not show the code that inputs the height, but I venture to say that part might be *too* simple, as user input needs to be rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is more efficient and afaict produces the same results:

```
static char hashes[80];
memset(hashes, '#', sizeof(hashes));
assert( height < sizeof(hashes) );

for( int line=0; line < height; line++ ) {
  printf( "%*.*s  %-*.*s\n",
    height, line+1, hashes,
    height, line+1, hashes );
}
```

You're a beginner, and there's more there than meets the eye.  The "trick" is that **printf**(3) has a language all its own in its format string, a language that's daunting at first.  Since your output is constant (hashes), you can work from a constant string and "format" the field by setting its size, truncating the string, and choosing left- or right-justification.

In learning C, you have to learn how to construct loops.  In using C, you have to learn the C standard library (and other libraries for the problem domain).  Frequently, those libraries let you avoid loops and thus simplify your code.